# AJAX callback does not see jQuery plugin's method

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I'm receiving a data from AJAX response and I'm trying to update a jQuery plugin with that value in the success callback:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/some/url',
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: (data) => {
      $(".my-rating").starRating('setRating', data.rating);
   }
});
```

I'm using the star-rating-svg plugin to show ratigns (http://nashio.github.io/star-rating-svg/demo/). The problem is that I'm having an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).starRating is not a function

However, this function works perfectly when is called outside AJAX callback. Do you know how to deal with this?

**EDIT:**

Larger piece of my code:

show.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/star-svg/src/jquery.star-rating-svg.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/star-svg/src/css/star-rating-svg.css">
   </head>    
   <body>
    <div class="my-rating mb-1"></div>

    <script>
    function getUserRating() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/some/url/rating',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: () => {
                    $(".my-rating").starRating('setRating', data.rating);
                }
            });
        }

    function webpageReady() {
            if($(".my-rating").is(':visible')) {

                $(".my-rating").starRating({
                    starSize: 20,
                    disableAfterRate: false,
                    callback: function(currentRating, $el){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/some/url/setRating',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {'rating' : currentRating}
                        });
                    }
                });
                getUserRating();
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">webpageReady();</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

rating.js

```
router.get("/some/url/rating", function (req, res) {
    Rating.findOne({'author.id': req.user._id}).populate("ratings").exec(function(err, rating){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            res.send({userRating : rating});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you try to declare your success function outside of the ajax call (instead of declaring it inline) ?

Comment: Are you sure the ajax call is successful? Did you check the console for errors? Did you try logging something in the `success` callback?

Comment: yes, ajax response is 100% successful and I'm receiving the data I want. I tried to make an outside done function $.ajax({...}).done(function(data){...}); but with the same result

Comment: Have you broken the code down to just the HTML and jquery calls? if so can you add that to your post?

Comment: @mrWalker, I threw together a modified version of Vasim's answer to test your problem and I was unable to duplicate your issue. So it might be caused by other code. Can you break down your code to a skeleton like Vasim's answer and test that and post it here?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the post. I have installed rating plugin using npm. Maybe the problem is that it should be installed globally somehow?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved: In a footer there was  another link to a jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, and I figured it out like this - I use jQuery StarRatingSvg v1.2.0:

```
callback: function(rating, $el){
  $.post( 
    URL, 
    { rating: rating, _token : "csrf_token" }
  ).done(function (resp) {
    $el.starRating('setRating', parseFloat(resp.rating), false);
  });
}
```

The callback function has two parameters: rating - the value set by a user when they click the stars, and $el - the rating element.

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

> Here is simple demo for this plugin

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/star-rating-svg@3.5.0/src/jquery.star-rating-svg.js"></script> 

</head>
<body>

<div class="my-rating"></div> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".my-rating").starRating({
    starSize: 25,
    callback: function(currentRating, $el){
        // make a server call here
    }
});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well that is clear, the point is how to change it's value inside an AJAX success callback?

Comment: This doesn't answer OPs question.